# Hay alguna forma de que el segundo catch no devuelva al principio del código? y devuelva al segundo try?

Tags: java, try-catch

Quiero saber si en java hay alguna forma de que cuando se equivoque el usuario en alguna entrada, por ejemplo en la tercer entrada no me devuelva hasta el principio, algunas personas me dijeron que en java no había forma de realizar esto pero se me hace algo ilógico, gracias

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombreFactura="";
        double precioProducto1=0.0;
        double precioProducto2=0.0;
        Scanner scannerNombreFactura = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scannerPrecioProducto1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scannerPrecioProducto2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("INGRESE EL NOMBRE DE LA FACTURA A REALIZAR: ");

        //NOMBRE FACTURA
        try{
            nombreFactura = scannerNombreFactura.nextLine();
        }catch (Exception e1){
            System.out.println("ERROR, INGRESO UN DATO INVALIDO");
            main(args);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //NOMBRE PRECIO 1
        try {
            System.out.println("INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL PRIMER PRODUCTO:");
            precioProducto1 = scannerPrecioProducto1.nextDouble();
        }catch (Exception e2){ //QUE DE ESTE CATCH NO ME DEVUELVA AL PRINCIPIO
            main(args);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //NOMBRE PRECIO 2
        try{
            System.out.println("INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL SEGUNDO PRODUCTO:");
            precioProducto2 = scannerPrecioProducto2.nextDouble();
        }catch(Exception e3){
            main(args);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me parece que lo que necesitas es un ciclo while

Answer (score 0):

No deberías hacer que la función `main` se llame a sí misma. Normalmente es mejor programar el código con ciclos y son pocos los casos en los que es mejor usar recursión.

---

No necesitas instanciar 5 scanners. Esto es excesivo:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scannerNombreFactura = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scannerPrecioProducto1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scannerPrecioProducto2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Con uno solo es suficiente.

---

Hay mejores opciones que `try catch` en este caso. Si revisas la documentación, verás que [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) cuenta con funciones que te dicen si la entrada es la esperada ([`hasNextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--), [`hasNextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--) y otras parecidas).

Además, puedes mover el código a nuevas funciones que se encarguen de devolver el tipo de dato esperado. De ese modo solo tendrás que llamar a la función deseada.

---

Tu código podría verse así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scanner;

    static String readLine(){
        while (!scanner.hasNextLine()){
           
 System.out.println("ERROR, INGRESO UN DATO INVÁLIDO");
            scanner.next();
        }
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    static double readDouble(){
        while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()){
            System.out.println("ERROR, INGRESO UN DATO INVÁLIDO");
            scanner.next();
        }
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombreFactura="";
        double precioProducto1=0.0;
        double precioProducto2=0.0;

        System.out.println("INGRESE EL NOMBRE DE LA FACTURA A REALIZAR: ");

        nombreFactura = readLine();
        
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL PRIMER PRODUCTO:");
        precioProducto1 = readDouble();

        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL SEGUNDO PRODUCTO:");
        precioProducto2 = readDouble();
    }
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aquí](https://ideone.com/lGNjbW).